# How to keep react-native-router components alive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm using `react-router-native`  to navigate trough my application. I've got a chat and I want it to keep mounted when I switch to an other component with a `<Link />`. I tested this by creating a `Text` and a `Button` and when I click the `Button`, the Text becomes a random Number; when I now switch to another component and come back, the number disappeared. Is there any solution that could keep the number loaded?

I set the router up like this:

```
  <NativeRouter>
    <View>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Recipes} /> 
      <Route path="/recipes" component={Recipes} /> 
      <Route path="/bookmarks" component={Bookmarks} />
      <Route path="/chat" component={Chat} />
      <Route path="/community" component={Community} />
      <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} /> 
    </View>
  </NativeRouter>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and constructive criticism. I'll try to improve my voting! @GhostCat